# Conditionally pass async function as argument in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to pass one of several functions as an argument to another function in Rust, depending on some condition. However, the compiler is returning the following error:

`` if` and `else` have incompatible types ``

```
expected fn item `fn() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {say_hello}`
   found fn item `fn() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {say_hi}`
```

main.rs:

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn greet<Fut>(f: impl Fn() -> Fut) where Fut: Future<Output = ()> {
    f().await;
}

async fn say_hello() {
    println!("Hello");
}

async fn say_hi() {
    println!("Hi");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let x = 5;

    let greet_func = if x < 10 {
        say_hello
    } else {
        say_hi
    };

    greet(&greet_func).await;
}
```

Comment: maybe your missing the () behind your function calls in the if else?

Comment: @MrIrrelevant wouldn't that set the value of greet_func to be ()?

Comment: `say_hello` and `say_hi` are not the same type, despite also returning something that implements `Future<Output = ()>`. You can either monomorphize the call to `greet` or box the contents that go into `greet_func`.

Comment: In Rust, each function has its own type, a so-called [function item type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-item.html). You can usually work around this by converting function item types (which are zero-sized) to function pointers. In this case, however, the two functions also have different return types. each returns `impl Future<Output = ()>`, but these two implementations of the `Future` trait are different types, so you can't convert them to function pointers of the same type.

Comment: @E_net4 thanks for the suggestion. Could you explain what it means to "box the contents"? For example, I tried changing `say_hello` to `Box::new(say_hello)` and changed the definition of greet to `async fn greet<Fut>(f: Box<impl Fn() -> Fut>) where Fut: Future<Output = ()>` but I still encounter a similar error as before

Comment: @user23050542 you must also box returned `impl Future`, since those are different types as well. Note that this will require changing `say_hi` and `say_hello` as well.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze thanks for help. If you would be able to show an updated version of the provided code it would be much appreciated! I am not so familiar with the Box type

Comment: @user23050542 Here you have a link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=778ebc46e8712c536c384aa0d5d87f5b). I've add comments that try to explain why boxing is needed.